# Simplify RecursiveIteratorIterator PHP function

Tags: php, recursion

I have the following functions show below which deletes a WordPress site. It works. However, I feel like there is a more efficient and simpler way to do it, but I am not sure how.

How can I simplify this to delete the /wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes folders and their contents as well as the PHP files which reside in the root directory of the WordPress site without deleting any other folders?

For example, a user may install another WordPress site in a sub-directory and when deleting a single WP site I don't want it to delete the files and folders of the site residing in the sub-directory.

I'm a bit of a noob so if someone can point me in the right direction.

```
// remove wp-admin folder and it's contents
$wpadmin = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory . '/wp-admin', RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);
foreach ($wpadmin as $fileinfo) {
    $todo = ($fileinfo->isDir() ? 'rmdir' : 'unlink');
    $todo($fileinfo->getRealPath());
};
rmdir($directory . '/wp-admin');

// remove wp-content folder and it's contents
$wpcontent = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory . '/wp-content', RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);
foreach ($wpcontent as $fileinfo) {
    $todo = ($fileinfo->isDir() ? 'rmdir' : 'unlink');
    $todo($fileinfo->getRealPath());
};
rmdir($directory . '/wp-content');

// remove wp-includes folder and it's contents
$wpincludes = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory . '/wp-includes', RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);
foreach ($wpincludes as $fileinfo) {
    $todo = ($fileinfo->isDir() ? 'rmdir' : 'unlink');
    $todo($fileinfo->getRealPath());
};
rmdir($directory . '/wp-includes');

// remove PHP files in WP root folder
$wpfiles = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);
foreach ($wpfiles as $fileinfo) {
    unlink($fileinfo->getRealPath());
}
```

Comment: There's a [great custom function in the documentation called `delTree`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#110489) that I'd look at in general. For the misc files in root, I'd probably just hard-code the ones that are in the [current repo's root](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress). Probably be careful with `.htaccess`, however, because you could break a multisite install.

Comment: @ChrisHaas ok i'll check that out, thx.